# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

Tags: oracle, kotlin, ojdbc

I have a Oracle database where one of the column are `XMLTYPE`.
When I run the query in console it gives me back the column and the xml content.

```
SELECT DATA_RECEIVED 
        FROM schema.taxCard
        WHERE FNR = (?) AND result = 'taxCardOK'
```

This is working fine. But in Kotlin code I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getSQLXML(NamedTypeAccessor.java:438)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getSQLXML(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1251)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getSQLXML(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
```

My code looks like this:

```
    fun Connection.hentSkattekortPaFnr(
    fnr: String
): String {
   val statement =  prepareStatement(
        """
            SELECT DATA_RECEIVED 
            FROM schema.taxCard
            WHERE FNR = (?) AND result = 'taxCardOK'
        """.trimIndent()
    ).apply {
        setString(1, fnr)
    }
    val resultSet = statement.executeQuery()
    val xml = resultSet.asSequence { resultSet.getSQLXML(1) }.first()
    return xml.string
}

    fun <T> ResultSet.asSequence(extract: () -> T ) : Sequence<T> = generateSequence{
    if (this.next()) extract() else null
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should debug to check that the DATA_RECEIVED column is really a SQLXML and not just a string containing XML data.  (e.g. using ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();)

Comment: I changed to resultSet.getString(1), but now it says that the sequence is empty. I am confused where the problem can rely.

Comment: Well that one is more a Kotlin problem in which I am not fluent, but what looks suspicious is the ".first()" and the "this.next()", my idea is that you are walking twice in the ResultSet...